# Mercator's Projection

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, projection

Consider the two-sphere,

(a) Show that the following map does provide a chart for $S^{2}$,

$\phi^{-1}(u, v) = (sech(u) cos(v), sech(u)sin(v), tanh(u))$

Compute the inverse of this map. What values can $(u, v)$ take?

(b) Show that, in this chart, meridians and parallels (of common chart used for Earth Surface) correspond to perpendicular straight lines (in the $(u, v)$ plane).

I am done with the inverse of the map. I have found the values of $(u, v)$ in terms of $(x, y, z)$. I know that the meridians and parallels in this projection are orthogonal, but I don't know how to prove it mathematically. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This is your homework, not ours. If you have done some work and show it, we might be willing to help.

Comment: I am sorry. I added some of the stuff.

Comment: OK, that's much better!

Comment: What is the inverse of the map?

Comment: $\phi(x, y, z) = (u, v) =\left(tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

The parallels are $z = \mbox{const}_1,$ while the latitudes are $\frac{y}{x} = \mbox{const}_2.$ Are the images straight lines? Well, the image of a latitude is obviously a vertical straight line ($u=\mbox{const}$), so the image of a meridian (longtitude) better be $v=\mbox{const},$ if the claim is correct. That does not seem to be true.